# Build a program with one simple GOTO

Tags: code-bowling

[image: The XKCD GOTO comic]

Your task is to build the largest program you can that uses exactly one GOTO, without which the entire program (or at least a huge chunk of it) must be completely restructured. The score is counted as the number of statements in your code that *change places* or *are newly introduced* (removing statements doesn't add to your score) when the code is restructured without the GOTO (others are allowed to challenge your restructuring by presenting a more elegant one). As this is code bowling, highest score wins.

Note: I do not claim any liability for velociraptor attacks by attempting this challenge.

Comment: The *one single* goto seems problematic. Every C code I can think of that uses a single goto can be trivially changed to use structured constructs. Multiple gotos however...

Comment: @Pubby's claim seems to hold against the current two solutions. Replacing `goto` with `switch` seems possible for both.

Comment: @Pubby How many goto's would you need to create a workable solution? If the problem as currently stated is impossible, I can create an alternative problem.

Comment: I think you're allowed to embed the cartoon, as long as there's a link too.

Comment: It doesn't qualify, but [I really did this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.c/_m0DEiFqCv0/gjdyRg_NzM0J).

Comment: Use ASM where you can't even remove the GOTO

Comment: Voting to close as it is unclear what is meant by "completely restructured", and as most languages allow any program to be restructured to a single statement, the scoring criterion is also hard to define a quantitative limit for.

Answer (score 11):

### C fizzbuzz

This solution runs around the idea of interrupts and label variables (gcc only, sorry). The program sets up a timer which periodically calls main, where we goto whichever place the last execution of our interrupt handler (main) told us we should.

I've never used timers or label variables before, so I think there is much to bowl here.

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc)
{
    static int run = 1;
    static int* gotoloc = &&init;
    static int num = 0;
    static int limit = 50;

    goto *gotoloc;
init:
    signal(SIGVTALRM, (void (*)(int)) main);
    gotoloc = &&loop;

    struct itimerval it_val;

    it_val.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
    it_val.it_value.tv_usec = 100000;
    it_val.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    it_val.it_interval.tv_usec = 100000;
    setitimer(ITIMER_VIRTUAL, &it_val, NULL);

    while(run);

loop:
    num = num + 1;
    run = num < limit;
    gotoloc = &&notfizz + (&&fizz - &&notfizz) * !(num % 3);
    return 1;

fizz:
    printf("fizz");
    gotoloc = &&notbuzz + (&&buzz - &&notbuzz) * !(num % 5);
    return 1;

notfizz:
    gotoloc = &&notfizzbuzz + (&&buzz - &&notfizzbuzz) * !(num % 5);
    return 1;

buzz:
    printf("buzz\n");
    gotoloc = &&loop;
    return 1;

notbuzz:
    printf("\n");
    gotoloc = &&loop;
    return 1;

notfizzbuzz:
    printf("%d\n", num);
    gotoloc = &&loop;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `run` should be declared `volatile`, otherwise `while(run)` can be "optimized" to `while(1)`. Or instead, just goto somewhere that calls `exit`.

Comment: @ugoren Good point. I turned on optimizations (O1, O2 and Os) and all those broke the program. Unfortunately just adding 'volatile' in front of run, gotoloc and num did not fix it. It might be gcc is not built for optimizing this kind of code.

Comment: Defining `volatile int num` outside of main should do it. With `static`, gcc thinks it knows who can mess with it.

Comment: unfortunately I can't create gotoloc outside the main, or I could, but I would have to set it to zero outside and then only reset in in the beginning of main if it's zero. And the appeal stats to fade. So I think it's best to say that I'm using C a bad way, gcc rightfully doesn't optimize it correctly so don't try.

Answer (score 5):

### Perl

I'm not very good at bowling, but I suspect this may interest the OP. This is a Sieve of Eratosthenes using a variable goto. Were this to be 'refactored', I doubt any of it would be reusable, other than perhaps the first few lines. When the sieve ends, all remaining `1`s in the `@primes` array correspond to prime values.

For added fun, no ands, ors, ternaries, conditionals or comparison operators of any kind are used.

```
@primes[2..1e4]=(1)x9999;
$a=2;
Y:
  $b=$a*~-$a;
X:
  $primes[$b+=$a+=$c=$a/100%2+$b/1e4%2]=0;
  goto"$c"^h;
Z:
```

Comment: In case there's any confusion as to why I'm posting this here, in a [separate question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/10908/) (now deleted), the OP stated that, "this was the question he actually wanted to ask", but wasn't sure if it was possible.

Comment: In case there's any confusion as to what question I posted, it was a question about building code using *only* GOTO's, rather than just one.

Comment: @JoeZeng I originally had three, but I reduced it to one so that it would be a valid solution to this problem as well.

Answer (score 3):

### C

My usage of macros perhaps doesn't make it "one GOTO".
And it's quite short, so "completely restructured" isn't much.
But here's my attempt anyway.

Reads a number from standard input, prints it modulu 3.

```
int main() {
    char s[100], *p, r=0;
    void *pl[] = { &&a, &&b, &&c, &&d, &&e, &&f, &&g, &&h, &&i, &&j, &&a, &&b, &&x, &&y, &&z }, *p1;
    p = gets(s);
    #define N(n) (pl+n)[!*p*60+*p-48];p++;goto *p1
    a: p1=N(0);
    b: p1=N(1);
    c: p1=N(2);
    d: p1=N(0);
    e: p1=N(1);
    f: p1=N(2);
    g: p1=N(0);
    h: p1=N(1);
    i: p1=N(2);
    j: p1=N(0);
    z: r++;
    y: r++;
    x: printf("%d\n", r);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, using macros like that isn't "one GOTO". But even then, you'd need to provide the restructuring of the program without using a GOTO. *Removing* statements doesn't add to your score.

Comment: Printing a number modulo 3 would be easy by just using a `printf` and `scanf`. Your solution's score would most likely be about 2 or 3.

Comment: You can easily write another program that prints `n%3`. But it won't use this program's logic, so I don't think it would be a restructuring of this program.

Comment: Fair point. I can't think of why anybody would ever *want* to program something that prints `n%3` in that way, though. It should be a program that becomes convoluted when the GOTO is *removed*, not when it is *introduced*.

Comment: "Why?" is irrelevant for this site - it's full of stupid ways to do stupid things. If you remove `goto`, the program won't work. But what did you expect - that the program would become convoluted by the removal alone?

Comment: By the removal and subsequent restructuring, yes. A simple example might be the use of goto to break out of multiple nested loops.